# TypeError: Type bytes32[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32[3] storage ref

Tags: solidity, testrpc, testing

**wrapper class to instantiate other classes**

```
contract WrapperCreator {

    function WrapperCreator() {
    }

    function createTopic(string name, bytes32[] resultNames, uint256 endBlock)
        returns (Topic tokenAddress)
    {
        return new Topic(name, resultNames, bettingEndBlock);
    }
}
```

**test cases for WrapperCreator**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/WrapperCreator.sol";

contract TestWrapperCreator {
    bytes32[3] resultNames;

    function beforeEach() {
        resultNames = new bytes32[](3);
        resultNames[0] = "first";
        resultNames[1] = "second";
        resultNames[2] = "third";
    }

    function testConstructor() {
        WrapperCreator wrapperCreator = WrapperCreator(DeployedAddresses.WrapperCreator());
        Topic testTopic = wrapperCreator.createTopic("test", resultNames, 1000000);

        Assert.equal(testTopic.getResultName(0), "first", "Expected result name matches");
    }
}
```

**I get the following errors:**

```
,../test/TestWrapperCreator.sol:11:23: TypeError: Type bytes32[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32[3] storage ref.
        resultNames = new bytes32[](3);
                      ^--------------^
,../test/TestWrapperCreator.sol:19:60: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from bytes32[3] storage ref to bytes32[] memory requested.
        Topic testTopic = eventCreator.createTopic("test", resultNames, 1000000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `createTopic` method expect `bytes32[]` type, a dynamic array of bytes32, but you are passing to it a `bytes32[3]`, a fixed size array of bytes32.

Change

```
bytes32[3] resultNames;
```

to

```
bytes32[] resultNames;
```

Please also note that you are passing a storage ref, so if the method modify the array the next test will read updated values.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use :

```
bytes32[3] resultNames;
function beforeEach() {

    bytes32[3] storage a ;
    resultNames =a;
    resultNames[0] = "first";
    resultNames[1] = "second";
    resultNames[2] = "third";
}
```